# Not filePath attribute in Enterprise Library 4.0 Configuration source block

Tags: enterprise-library

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/EnterpriseLibraryExternalConfigurationSourceApplicationBlockSettings.aspx) but couldn't find File entry in properties windows. When I tried to add filePath attribute manually (taken from same tutorial) i get following error "Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'filePath'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2403/configurationsourceprop.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2403/configurationsourceprop.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the File entry, you need to bring up the properties window (if it's not open) by hitting F4.  Then click on the file configuration source element in the Enterprise Library configuration tool.  This will display the Name and File properties that can be set.

**Update**

Thanks for the screen shot.  To get the File Configuration Source, right click on Configuration Sources and then select New->File Configuration Source.  Then you will be able to set the File property in that new element.

Comment: As you can see in screenshot I added to description I can open properties, but File is not there

Comment: Because EL configuration can be confusing and non-intuitive?  :)

Comment: And because it by default creates System source instead of none